Calculate subtotals of the output of sort-unique command
I have a file that is generated using command | sort | uniq -c
city.txt
2 mumbaiXa
3 mumbaiXb
1 mumbaiXp
5 delhiXn
4 delhiXz
1 parisXs
7 parisXt
1 parisXa
9 parisXe

I am trying to split on X and get the count of each city:
expected output:
mumbai 6
delhi 9
paris 18

I tried this but that did not return the expected result.
grep 'X' city.txt | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F 'X' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c


Update:
The data file looks like this...
   1904 mumbaiXa
   1167 mumbaiXa
    830 mumbaiXb
    565 mumbaiXp
    424 delhiXn
    423 delhiXz

I gave a simplified version and changed the text.

Cityname does not contain space like new york.

Nothing changed in the update? The solutions below should work in either case

does the final output need to be sorted?

Yes. final output should be sorted.


I have a file that is generated using command | sort | uniq -c
city.txt
2 mumbaiXa
3 mumbaiXb
1 mumbaiXp
5 delhiXn
4 delhiXz
1 parisXs
7 parisXt
1 parisXa
9 parisXe


If you are allowed to call command again and it will give exactly same output you might get desired totals by dropping X and what is after it, before ramming that into following command, which might be done e.g. following way
command | awk 'BEGIN{FS="X"}{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c

otherwise if you wish to use ... | sort | uniq -c you should repeat cityname times quantity, let city.txt content be
2 mumbaiXa
3 mumbaiXb
1 mumbaiXp
5 delhiXn
4 delhiXz
1 parisXs
7 parisXt
1 parisXa
9 parisXe

then
awk 'sub(/X.*/,""){for(i=1;i<=$1;i+=1){print $2}}' city.txt | sort | uniq -c

gives output
  9 delhi
  6 mumbai
 18 paris

Explanation: for every line where subsitution of X followed by zero-or-more of any character was done I use for loop to print 2nd field number of times specified in 1st field.

copy pasted the command that contains sub(/X.*/,"") and it worked. Appreciate your help.

You can avoid the useless grep and other associated inefficiencies by implementing everything in a single Awk script.
The crucial change here is the sub to replace everything after X in the key; but the surrounding refactoring is hopefully also useful.
awk '/X/ {
    k = $2
    sub(/X.*/, "", k)
    a[k] += $1
}
END {
    for(k in a)
        print(a[k], k)
}' city.txt

Demo: https://ideone.com/8fvpgw
If your city names can contain spaces, maybe use substr($0, length($1)+2) instead of $2.
Demo: https://ideone.com/G4ZwJR
Replacing sort | uniq -c with an Awk associative array is a very common and basic idiom; if you are using Awk anyway, investing half an hour on a tutorial is time well spent.

have you considered a gap-less concat in lieu of +2 every substr()? i.e. to right side of all code (and beyond the right most single quote) but before city.txt add __='__' then alter the substr(…) to substr($0, length(__$1))', which would emulate the same effect as +2 on the starting index by concat-ing "__" with $1

You'd need to fix the quoting but yes, that would work too.

is it better now

that's why i said add __='__' on right hand side before city.txt but outside of all normal code, and make it a command line variable assignment. like awk '{ do-some-stuff }' __='__' city.txt

Riiight, seems like an overcomplication to me but sure.

but you know it actually takes awk fewer backend instructions to do so, since you're already calling length() anyway.

You can use Ruby to replace the entire pipe:
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{cnt=Hash.new(0)}
key=$F[1][/^[^X]+/]
cnt[key]=cnt[key]+=$F[0].to_i
END{p cnt }' file 

Prints:
{"mumbai"=>6, "delhi"=>9, "paris"=>18}

If you want formatting similar:
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{cnt=Hash.new(0)}
key=$F[1][/^[^X]+/]
cnt[key]=cnt[key]+=$F[0].to_i
END{col1=cnt.values.map(&:to_s).max_by{|k| k.length}.length
    puts cnt.map{|k,v| "#{v.to_s.rjust(col1+2)} #{k}"} }' file 

Prints:
   6 mumbai
   9 delhi
  18 Paris

Or in the order of your original example, and in a table:
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{cnt=Hash.new(0)}
key=$F[1][/^[^X]+/]
cnt[key]=cnt[key]+=$F[0].to_i
END{col1=cnt.keys.map(&:to_s).max_by{|k| k.length}.length
    col2=cnt.values.map(&:to_s).max_by{|v| v.length}.length
    puts cnt.map{|k,v| "#{k.to_s.ljust(col1)} #{v.to_s.rjust(col2)}"} }' file 

Prints:
mumbai  6
delhi   9
paris  18


Using any awk, given input grouped by city as your example is:
$ awk -F'[ X]' '$2 != prev{ if (NR>1) print tot, prev; tot=0; prev=$2} {tot+=$1} END{print tot, prev}' city.txt
6 mumbai
9 delhi
18 paris

or if you prefer (or your input isn't grouped and you don't want to sort it first for some reason):
$ awk -F'[ X]' '{tot[$2]+=$1} END{for (city in tot) print  tot[city], city}' city.txt
delhi 9
mumbai 6
paris 18

